# A confusion regarding threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Level beginner. I have a confusion regarding the thread creation methods in python. To be specific is there any difference between the following two approaches:

1. In first approach I am using `import thread` module and later I am creating a thread by this code `thread.start_new_thread(myfunction,())` as myfunction() doesn't have any args.
2. In second approach I am using `from threading import Thread` and later I am creating threads by doing something like this: `t = Thread(target=myfunction)`then `t.start()`

The reason why I am asking is because my programme works fine for second approach but when I use first approach it doesn't works as intended. I am working on a Client-Server programme. Thanks

The code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
from threading import Thread
import thread

data = 'default'
tcpSocket = ''
def start_server():
    global tcpSocket
    tcpSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    tcpSocket.bind(('',1520))
    tcpSocket.listen(3)
    print "Server is up...."

def service():
    global tcpSocket    
    (clientSocket,address) = tcpSocket.accept()
    print "Client connected with: ", address
   #    data = 'default'

    send_data(clientSocket,"Server: This is server\n")
    global data
    while len(data):
        data = receive_data(clientSocket)
        send_data(clientSocket,"Client: "+data)

    print "Client exited....\nShutting the server"
    clientSocket.close()
    tcpSocket.close()

def send_data(socket,data):
    socket.send(data)
    def receive_data(socket):
    global data 
    data = socket.recv(2048)
    return data


start_server()

for i in range(2):
    t = Thread(target=service)
    t.start()
#thread.start_new_thread(service,())
```

Comment: Why "it doesn't work as intended"?

Comment: The server doesn't start up completely. I mean the code before socket.accept() works but after that programme exits without any error. I can post the code but it will make this post too long!

Comment: You most certainly want to use the higher-level `threading` module, so if that works, don't worry about the lower-level `thread`.

Comment: Use `threading`.  `thread` is a low-level module better suited for experts - and even they rarely use it.  In Python3, `thread` is renamed to `_thread` to further discourage its use.

Comment: @shx2 I was just curious to know the reason.

Comment: For anyone to know the reason, you would have to show all your code. And then nobody would care enough to dig into it - LOL ;-)

Comment: My guess is that your problem lies in the fact that when the main thread dies, it takes the entire process with it.
However, when the main function ends, the GC kills off all remaining objects calling their d'tor methods and there Thread prevents from the main thread to end completely until the sub-thread has finished

Comment: @immortal can you explain bit more please. I didn't get it sorry. How can main thread die? It should start service() in my code then the server waits for client. I guess it should wait rather than to die.

Comment: @pss sorry, got posted mid-writting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @immortal can you explain bit more please. I didn't get it sorry. How can main thread die? It should start service() in my code then the server waits for client. I guess it should wait rather than to die.

Your main thread calls:

```
start_server()
```

and that returns.  Then your main thread executes this:

```
for i in range(2):
    t = Thread(target=service)
    t.start()
#thread.start_new_thread(service,())
```

Those also complete almost instantly, and then your main thread ends.

At that point, the main thread is *done*.  Python enters its interpreter shutdown code.

Part of the shutdown code is *waiting* to `.join()` all (non-daemon) threads created by the `threading` module.  That's one of the reasons it's far better *not* to use `thread` unless you know exactly what you're doing.  For example, if you're me ;-) But the only times I've ever used `thread` are in the *implementation* of `threading`, and to write test code for the `thread` module.

You're entirely on your own to manage all aspects of a `thread` module thread's life.  Python's shutdown code doesn't wait for those threads.  The interpreter simply exits, ignoring them completely, and the OS kills them off (well, that's really up to the OS, but on all major platforms I know of the OS does just kill them ungracefully in midstream).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Should I use setDaemon(True) somewhere? But I don't know where. This is an interesting concept for me but bit complicated too.

Comment: Advise never using daemon threads unless you know exactly what you're doing.  Strive instead to shut down your threads cleanly - save the thread objects in a list and explicitly `.join()` them yourself. You don't need *more* magic at the start, you need *less* ;-) "Explicit is better than implicit"